# Load external JSP page onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am not sure if I can do this. I have a menu in `menu.jsp` file. Till now, I included the menu in my `original.jsp`. Now, I want to provide a button instead of my `menu.jsp` and when the user clicks on the button, I want to load `menu.jsp`. How can I do that? I want to make my page look like Microsoft outlook **Navigation Pane**. I have this right now... button is in original.jsp. Other div's are in menu.jsp

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
    $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
    if(hidden){
        $('.sidebarmenu,.image').animate({
        left: '0px'
    },500)
    } else {
    $('.sidebarmenu,.image').animate({
        left: '-210px'
    },500)
    }
    $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);
});
});
<div id="content">
<div id="pageNav"  style="z-index:9999; position:relative;height:180px;">
   <button id="showmenu" type="button">Hide menu</button>
    <div class="sidebarmenu" style="position: absolute;">
        Menu List
        <img class="image" src="http://www.glamquotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/smile.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: -1?? Is it not possible?? It would be nice if you give the reason for -1.. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Do you mean show/don't show menu?  Is there any reason you need to load the menu from the server each time the user clicks the button (ie the content will vary)?

Comment: The external JSP file is my menu. I want to show it in 20 other pages. So instead of writing the same code in 20 other pages, i want to load it on click.